# How to list only some events in my iphone table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application uses Events framework to add events to calendar and it works fine. The user will add his events to fire at a certain time with the standard events UI.

Then I want to read only the events created using this application and not to list all the events on the iPhone calendar application. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

when cration an event, try to flag or tag them. Then, in tableView data source, chack your flags/tags

Answer (score 0):

*EKEvent* object contains *eventIdentifier* property. I have not used it ever, so not having much idea about this. But still I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Isn't it or you are in search of something else?

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot find a good way to flag the items, you could save a unique identifier of all events that are created, when they are created, and then compare this list of events to the ones loaded from the calendar.